# DialogFragment created from Fragment crashed after orientation changed

Tags: android, onactivityresult, dialogfragment

The problem is that DialogFragment has target not in fragment manager after orientation was changed; so overriding onDestroyView() and setting setRetainInstance(true) to Dialogfragment did not solve it!!

this code from MyFragment.java

```
public class MyFragment extends ListFragment {
    //...
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK)
            return;
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_TO_DIALOG_FRAGMENT) {
            //...
        }
    }

    private void show_my_dialog_fragment(int index) { 
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.addToBackStack(null);

        DialogFragment fragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance(index);
        fragment.setTargetFragment(this, REQUEST_TO_DIALOG_FRAGMENT);
        fragment.show(ft, null);
    }
}
```

and this from MyDialogFragment.java

```
MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    //...
    private void sendResult(int resultCode) {
        if (getTargetFragment() == null)
            return;
        getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), resultCode, null);
    }
}
```

https://github.com/imla-assuom/DrawerDialogFragment.git

LogCat for the example app:

```
 10-20 07:34:26.016    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:320>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM Build: I0404c4692afb8623f95c43aeb6d5e13ed4b30ddbDate: 11/06/13
10-20 07:34:26.046    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
10-20 07:34:36.776    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment W/View﹕ requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.ListView{64e905e8 IFED.VC. ......ID -480,0-0,942 #7f080002 app:id/navigation_drawer} during layout: running second layout pass
10-20 07:34:36.776    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment I/MyFragment﹕ onActivityResult
10-20 07:34:41.060    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ Failure saving state: MyDialogFragment{64e88348 #2} has target not in fragment manager: MyFragment{64e881b0}
10-20 07:34:41.070    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ Activity state:
10-20 07:34:41.070    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ Local Activity 64e87320 State:
10-20 07:34:41.070    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ mResumed=false mStopped=false mFinished=false
10-20 07:34:41.070    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ mLoadersStarted=true
10-20 07:34:41.070    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ mChangingConfigurations=true
10-20 07:34:41.070    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ mCurrentConfig={1.0 ?mcc?mnc en_US ldltr sw600dp w960dp h527dp 320dpi lrg land finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h s.24}
10-20 07:34:41.070    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ Active Fragments in 64e87420:
10-20 07:34:41.070    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ #0: NavigationDrawerFragment{64e87ff8 #0 id=0x7f080002}
10-20 07:34:41.070    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ mFragmentId=#7f080002 mContainerId=#7f080000 mTag=null
10-20 07:34:41.070    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ mState=4 mIndex=0 mWho=android:fragment:0 mBackStackNesting=0
10-20 07:34:41.070    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ mAdded=true mRemoving=false mResumed=false mFromLayout=true mInLayout=true
10-20 07:34:41.070    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ mHidden=false mDetached=false mMenuVisible=true mHasMenu=true
10-20 07:34:41.070    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ mRetainInstance=false mRetaining=false mUserVisibleHint=true
10-20 07:34:41.070    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ mFragmentManager=FragmentManager{64e87420 in MainActivity{64e87320}}
10-20 07:34:41.070    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ mActivity=com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment.MainActivity@64e87320
10-20 07:34:41.070    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ mSavedViewState={2131230722=AbsListView.SavedState{64ea3fe8 selectedId=-9223372036854775808 firstId=-1 viewTop=0 position=0 height=942 filter=null checkState={0=true}}}
10-20 07:34:41.070    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ [ 10-20 07:34:41.070  4931: 4931 E/FragmentManager ]
    mView=android.widget.ListView{64e905e8 IFED.VC. ......ID -480,0-0,942 #7f080002 app:id/navigation_drawer}
10-20 07:34:41.070    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ #1: MyFragment{64e90310 #1 id=0x7f080001}
10-20 07:34:41.070    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ mFragmentId=#7f080001 mContainerId=#7f080001 mTag=null
10-20 07:34:41.070    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ mState=4 mIndex=1 mWho=android:fragment:1 mBackStackNesting=0
10-20 07:34:41.070    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ mAdded=true mRemoving=false mResumed=false mFromLayout=false mInLayout=false
10-20 07:34:41.070    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ mHidden=false mDetached=false mMenuVisible=true mHasMenu=false
10-20 07:34:41.070    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ mRetainInstance=false mRetaining=false mUserVisibleHint=true
10-20 07:34:41.070    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ mFragmentManager=FragmentManager{64e87420 in MainActivity{64e87320}}
10-20 07:34:41.070    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ mActivity=com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment.MainActivity@64e87320
10-20 07:34:41.070    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ mSavedViewState={2131230723=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@60aa32c0}
10-20 07:34:41.080    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ mContainer=android.widget.FrameLayout{64e8fd40 V.E..... ........ 0,0-1920,942 #7f080001 app:id/container}
10-20 07:34:41.080    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ mView=android.widget.RelativeLayout{64e97300 V.E..... ........ 0,0-1920,942}
10-20 07:34:41.080    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ #2: MyDialogFragment{64e88348 #2}
10-20 07:34:41.080    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ mFragmentId=#0 mContainerId=#0 mTag=null
10-20 07:34:41.080    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ mState=4
10-20 07:34:41.080    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ mIndex=2 mWho=android:fragment:2 mBackStackNesting=1
10-20 07:34:41.080    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ mAdded=true mRemoving=false mResumed=false mFromLayout=false mInLayout=false
10-20 07:34:41.080    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ mHidden=false mDetached=false mMenuVisible=true mHasMenu=false
10-20 07:34:41.080    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ mRetainInstance=false mRetaining=false mUserVisibleHint=true
10-20 07:34:41.080    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ mFragmentManager=FragmentManager{64e87420 in MainActivity{64e87320}}
10-20 07:34:41.080    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ mActivity=com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment.MainActivity@64e87320
10-20 07:34:41.080    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ mArguments=Bundle[{INDEX=2}]
10-20 07:34:41.080    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ mSavedViewState={2131230723=android.view.AbsSavedState$1@60aa32c0}
10-20 07:34:41.080    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ mTarget=MyFragment{64e881b0} mTargetRequestCode=1
10-20 07:34:41.080    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ mView=android.widget.RelativeLayout{64e931b0 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-1128,1022}
10-20 07:34:41.080    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ DialogFragment:
10-20 07:34:41.080    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ mStyle=1 mTheme=0x0
10-20 07:34:41.080    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ mCancelable=true mShowsDialog=true mBackStackId=0
10-20 07:34:41.080    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ mDialog=android.app.Dialog@64e92dc0
10-20 07:34:41.080    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ mViewDestroyed=false mDismissed=false mShownByMe=false
10-20 07:34:41.080    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ Added Fragments:
10-20 07:34:41.080    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ #0: NavigationDrawerFragment{64e87ff8 #0 id=0x7f080002}
10-20 07:34:41.080    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ #1: MyDialogFragment{64e88348 #2}
10-20 07:34:41.080    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ #2:
10-20 07:34:41.080    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ MyFragment{64e90310 #1 id=0x7f080001}
10-20 07:34:41.080    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ Fragments Created Menus:
10-20 07:34:41.080    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ #0: NavigationDrawerFragment{64e87ff8 #0 id=0x7f080002}
10-20 07:34:41.080    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ Back Stack:
10-20 07:34:41.080    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ #0: BackStackEntry{64e88530 #0}
10-20 07:34:41.080    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ mName=null mIndex=0 mCommitted=false
10-20 07:34:41.080    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ Operations:
10-20 07:34:41.080    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ Op #0: ADD MyDialogFragment{64e88348 #2}
10-20 07:34:41.080    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ Back Stack Indices:
10-20 07:34:41.080    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ #0: BackStackEntry{64e88530 #0}
10-20 07:34:41.080    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ FragmentManager misc state:
10-20 07:34:41.080    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ mActivity=com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment.MainActivity@64e87320
10-20 07:34:41.080    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ mContainer=android.app.Activity$1@64e87498
10-20 07:34:41.090    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ mCurState=4 mStateSaved=true mDestroyed=false
10-20 07:34:41.090    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ ViewRoot:
10-20 07:34:41.090    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ mAdded=true mRemoved=false
10-20 07:34:41.090    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ mConsumeBatchedInputScheduled=false
10-20 07:34:41.090    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ mPendingInputEventCount=0
10-20 07:34:41.090    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ mProcessInputEventsScheduled=false
10-20 07:34:41.090    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ mTraversalScheduled=false
10-20 07:34:41.090    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ android.view.ViewRootImpl$NativePreImeInputStage: mQueueLength=0
10-20 07:34:41.090    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage: mQueueLength=0
10-20 07:34:41.090    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ android.view.ViewRootImpl$NativePostImeInputStage: mQueueLength=0
10-20 07:34:41.090    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ Choreographer:
10-20 07:34:41.090    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ mFrameScheduled=false
10-20 07:34:41.090    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ mLastFrameTime=3330181 (4246 ms ago)
10-20 07:34:41.090    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ [ 10-20 07:34:41.090  4931: 4931 E/FragmentManager ]
    View Hierarchy:
10-20 07:34:41.090    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{64e88610 V.E..... R....... 0,0-1920,1104}
10-20 07:34:41.090    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout{64e88c48 V.ED.... ........ 0,0-1920,1104 #1020313 android:id/action_bar_overlay_layout}
10-20 07:34:41.090    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.FrameLayout{64e89838 V.E..... ........ 0,162-1920,1104 #1020002 android:id/content}
10-20 07:34:41.090    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout{64e8f5c8 VFE..... .F...... 0,0-1920,942 #7f080000 app:id/drawer_layout}
10-20 07:34:41.090    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.FrameLayout{64e8fd40 V.E..... ........ 0,0-1920,942 #7f080001 app:id/container}
10-20 07:34:41.090    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.RelativeLayout{64e97300 V.E..... ........ 0,0-1920,942}
10-20 07:34:41.090    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.TextView{64e97748 V.ED..C. ........ 128,32-1792,910 #7f080003 app:id/section_label}
10-20 07:34:41.090    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.ListView{64e905e8 IFED.VC. ......ID -480,0-0,942 #7f080002 app:id/navigation_drawer}
10-20 07:34:41.090    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.TextView{64e9c120 V.ED.... .....AI. 0,0-480,96 #1020014 android:id/text1}
10-20 07:34:41.090    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.TextView{64e9cc08 V.ED.... ......I. 0,95-480,191 #1020014 android:id/text1}
10-20 07:34:41.090    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.TextView{64e9d598 V.ED.... ......I. 0,190-480,286 #1020014 android:id/text1}
10-20 07:34:41.090    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer{64e89c30 V.ED.... ........ 0,50-1920,162 #1020314 android:id/action_bar_container}
10-20 07:34:41.090    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView{64e8a130 V.E..... ........ 0,0-1920,112 #1020315 android:id/action_bar}
10-20 07:34:41.090    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.LinearLayout{64e8a690 VFE...C. ........ 0,0-538,112}
10-20 07:34:41.090    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView$HomeView{64e8b748 V.E..... ........ 0,0-129,112}
10-20 07:34:41.090    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.ImageView{64e8bad8 V.ED.... ........ 0,40-32,72 #102025a android:id/up}
10-20 07:34:41.090    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.ImageView{64e8be38 V.ED.... ........ 25,8-121,104 #102002c android:id/home}
10-20 07:34:41.090    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.LinearLayout{64e8d010 V.E..... ........ 129,31-538,80}
10-20 07:34:41.090    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ [ 10-20 07:34:41.100  4931: 4931 E/FragmentManager ]
    android.widget.TextView{64e8d318 V.ED.... ........ 0,0-393,49 #1020265 android:id/action_bar_title}
10-20 07:34:41.100    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ android.widget.TextView{64e8df98 G.ED.... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #1020266 android:id/action_bar_subtitle}
10-20 07:34:41.100    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView{64e9fbd0 V.ED.... ........ 1558,0-1920,112}
10-20 07:34:41.100    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView{64ea1430 VFED..CL ........ 0,0-232,112 #7f080005 app:id/action_example}
10-20 07:34:41.100    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuPresenter$OverflowMenuButton{64e9ef30 VFED..C. ........ 234,0-362,112}
10-20 07:34:41.100    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView{64e8e5b0 G.E..... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #1020316 android:id/action_context_bar}
10-20 07:34:41.100    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer{64e8ea78 G.ED.... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #1020317 android:id/split_action_bar}
10-20 07:34:41.100    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ Looper (main, tid 1) {64dfdf40}
10-20 07:34:41.100    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ Message 0: { when=-32ms what=90 target=com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler }
10-20 07:34:41.100    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ Message 1: { when=-32ms what=65 target=com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler }
10-20 07:34:41.100    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ Message 2: { when=-32ms what=95 target=com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler }
10-20 07:34:41.100    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/FragmentManager﹕ (Total messages: 3, idling=false, quitting=false)
10-20 07:34:41.100    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
10-20 07:34:41.100    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment, PID: 4931
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failure saving state: MyDialogFragment{64e88348 #2} has target not in fragment manager: MyFragment{64e881b0}
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveAllState(FragmentManager.java:1651)
            at android.app.Activity.onSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1205)
            at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1153)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1223)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3698)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1202)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
10-20 07:34:44.083    4931-4931/com.example.imla.drawerdialogefragment I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 4931 SIG: 9
```

Comment: can you post the logcat output of the exception?

Comment: Sorry, I know too much lines.. !!

Answer (score 0):

this depends a bit on the android version you use. in lower version there is no childfragment manager. to solve this problem you can remove this dialog in the onpause() (is called before oriantion changed) of main fragment and replace it in onresume() (is called afteroriantion changed)